# Gem install susy results in "undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: rubygems, terminal, installation, compass-sass, susy-compass

OS: Ubuntu 12.04
Ruby version: ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [i686-linux]

When I try to install Susy via `gem install susy`, the terminal gives me the following response:

`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)`
`undefined method 'size' for nil:NilClass`

Google/Stackoverflow search has not helped me so far

Comment: exactly the same problem with `gem install compass` btw. Even un- and reinstalled the whole ruby environment. To no avail

Comment: having same issue trying to install rails -v 3.2.11. I've just recently(last week) installed it and it worked without problems. Now it errors with the same message. I can install other gems, no problem.